# Problem in fetching data from multiple collections using lookup in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

Currently I have three Collection "User" , "UserLocation" & "UserAddress" which are related with each other.

Below are the Schema

**UserModel**

```
var userTable = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userTable );
```

**UserLocationModel**

```
var userLocationTable = new Schema({
  location : String,
  user_id :{
    type : ObjectId,
    ref : 'user',
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('userLocation',userLocationTable);
```

**UserAddressModel**

```
var userAddressTable = new Schema({
    userLocationID : {
      type : ObjectID,
      ref : 'userLocation',
    },
   address : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('userAddress',userAddressTable);
```

**My Code**

```
UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "userlocations",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "user_id",
                "as": "location"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$location"
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "useraddresses",  
                "localField": "location._id",
                "foreignField": "userLocationID",
                "as": "location.address"
            }
        },
    ]).exec((err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(data);
    })
```

**Current Output**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5d8b1e6ca4d1ab5e54f1b8ee",
    "name": "Shivam",
    "email": "ee@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "location": {
        "_id": "5d8b1e6ca4d1ab5e54f1b8ef",
        "location": "Mumbai",
        "user_id": "5d8b1e6ca4d1ab5e54f1b8ee",
        "__v": 0,
        "address": []
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5d8b3a740b6fee55ac39a61d",
    "name": "ameet",
    "email": "ddt@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "location": {
        "_id": "5d8b3a740b6fee55ac39a61e",
        "location": "sion",
        "user_id": "5d8b3a740b6fee55ac39a61d",
        "__v": 0,
        "address": []
    }
}
]
```

Here the problem is I am not able to fetch the data from UserAddress Model. I have tried all the possible ways but unable to fetch the data from UserAddress Collection. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: you have userLocationID saved in UserAddressModel but in lookup you're using  "foreignField": "userLocation", not  "foreignField": "userLocationID",

Comment: @sushantmehta I have edited the question and updated userLocation to userLocationID  still i am not able to fetch

Comment: can you try after changing userAddresss to userAddresses in lookup.from

Comment: Updated the question and tried but still nothing happen

Comment: make it useraddresses as mongo saves collection in lowercase and plural

Comment: MongoDB does not *"save in lowercase", `mongoose` does. That's an important distinction to understand. It's also a basic principle of the "how to join" which has been explained many times before. The **collection name** needs to be exactly what MongoDB expects it to be **on the server** in order to actually do anything. BTW, you appear to have based your code on a *very* old post. `$lookup` has far more effective ways to implement *chained joins* without needing `$unwind. See the second marked duplicate.